# How to extend the nested ternary operators

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, ternary-operator

```
return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
```

The above expression used in array sort by value operation.

How can I extend this ternary operators to avoid non-complaint coding standard (Sonar cube detected this as a Major code smell/non-compliant) ?

Can we do this without using any extra variable?

Comment: extend? You mean expand it?

Comment: Yes, can be expanded!

Comment: Abusing the conditional operator certainly can make code hard to read, but I wouldn't say that's the case here. I wonder if a set of parens would satisfy the linter. `return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0);` I'd personally write it without the parens but with a line break so that the `a < b` and `b > a` are aligned vertically.

Comment: Reading their [list of Code Smells](https://www.sonarsource.com/why-us/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjs/rules.html#Code_Smell_Detection), they disallow the use of the conditional operator completely: [*"The ternary operator should not be used"*](https://www.sonarsource.com/why-us/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjs/rules.html#RSPEC-1774) I think they have a nice list of code recommendations, but IMO that one goes a little too far.

Comment: They must have the ability to configure or apply different modes, because strangely, that page has both [*"Trailing commas should be used"*](https://www.sonarsource.com/why-us/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjs/rules.html#RSPEC-1774) as well as [*"Trailing commas should not be used"*](https://www.sonarsource.com/why-us/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjs/rules.html#RSPEC-1537).

Comment: ...and if `a` and `b` are numbers, and you can substitute any positive/negative number for `1` and `-1`, then you could simply do `return a - b;`

Comment: That list of Code Smells shows all available rules, but they're not all on by default. Contradictory rules are provided because different shops have different standards.

Answer (score 4):

I think SonarQube might be complaining about the nested ternary operators, which can be a bit confusing. You can use this:

```
if (a < b) return -1;
if (a > b) return 1;
return 0;
```

A simple way to write a comparison function for *numbers* would be:

```
return a - b;
```

Comment: The OP may get a warning about [missing curly braces](https://www.sonarsource.com/why-us/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjs/rules.html#RSPEC-121), though I think your solution is just fine.

Comment: I was looking for [brace usage](https://www.sonarsource.com/why-us/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjs/rules.html#RSPEC-2681) on the SonarQube site, and I think that will pass.

Comment: Yes, that rule certainly makes it sound like it'll pass. They seem to have rules that overlap and seemingly contradict, like the ones I noted under the question. There must be some way to tweak the configuration to your liking.

Comment: I agree, and also to suppress rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a < b) { 
  return -1; 
} else if (a > b) { 
  return 1; 
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Almost the same same content (just **less** readable, and more complicated to look at) as the one from Jordao; but without any further explanations.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a < b) { 
  return -1; 
} 
return + (a > b);
```

Comment: But...this doesn't return the same values as the original code.

Comment: @nnnnnn now it does

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes it happens without a nested ternary operator. For example, I was using `||` (or operator) for my condition and it was showing that warning. **I had to disable that rule in `VS code`**. It is now working fine.

Comment: I don't think this answer adds anything to this 4 year old question.

Comment: Actually, I was facing this warning without using any nested ternary operation. And I have got no solution here. That's why I suggested this.